# ReferenceError: dingwun is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

So basically like i'm trying to make text appear using buttons but I did everything, I tried changing the id a few times like myFunction() or myButton() but none work. I believe the id has nothing to do with this and repl.it is stupid. If it does work please help me please ok

I've tried using different ids as said before, I tried putting ;s and no ;s and I even tried asking supercommunity but no one answered.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>sunny's website</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style>
      .button {
        color:white;
        background-color:green;
        padding:10px 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .button:hover {
        background-color: black;
      }
      .button:active {
        cursor: help;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <h1>welcome<h1>
    <button onclick="dingwun()" class="button">click me!</button>
    <h2>click the thing to reveal!:</h2>
    <p id="vari"></p>
    <script>
        function dingwun() {
          var x = document:getElementById("vari");
          x.innerHTML = "coolio";
        }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have syntax errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
document:getElementById("vari");
```

Should be:

```
document.getElementById("vari");
```

NOTES:

Don't use `.innerHTML` when the string doesn't contain any HTML as `.innerHTML` has performance and security implications. Instead, use `.textContent`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>sunny's website</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style>
      .button {
        color:white;
        background-color:green;
        padding:10px 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .button:hover {
        background-color: black;
      }
      .button:active {
        cursor: help;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <h1>welcome<h1>
    <button onclick="dingwun()" class="button">click me!</button>
    <h2>click the thing to reveal!:</h2>
    <p id="vari"></p>
    <script>
        function dingwun() {
          var x = document.getElementById("vari");
          x.textContent = "coolio";
        }
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in command `document:getElementById("vari")`, it should be a fullstop at the place of semicolon. `document.getElementById("vari")`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>sunny's website</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style>
      .button {
        color:white;
        background-color:green;
        padding:10px 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .button:hover {
        background-color: black;
      }
      .button:active {
        cursor: help;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <h1>welcome<h1>
    <button onclick="dingwun()" class="button">click me!</button>
    <h2>click the thing to reveal!:</h2>
    <p id="vari"></p>
    <script>
        function dingwun() {
          var x = document.getElementById("vari");
          x.innerHTML = "coolio";
        }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually use `:` in `document:getElementById("vari")` you have to use `.` like `document.getElementById("vari")`. Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>sunny's website</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style>
      .button {
        color:white;
        background-color:green;
        padding:10px 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .button:hover {
        background-color: black;
      }
      .button:active {
        cursor: help;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <h1>welcome<h1>
    <button onclick="dingwun()" class="button">click me!</button>
    <h2>click the thing to reveal!:</h2>
    <p id="vari"></p>
    <script>
        function dingwun() {
          var x = document.getElementById("vari");
          x.innerHTML = "coolio";
        }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```